# Yii2.0 pagination issue second page not working

Tags: yii2

How do I do a pagination? I have a search form and a search button which passes in a date range. The first page is working successfully, however when I click on the second page, it shows everything. How do I pass the date range into my pagination?

**EDIT:** 
Below is my ReportSearch.php (model)

```
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5,
            //'params' => array('search' => 'true', 'from_dt'=>$stockmovement_summary_from_sales_date, 'to_dt'=> $stockmovement_summary_to_sales_date),
        ],
    ]);

    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'd_item.desc_e_tx' => SORT_ASC,
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'd_item.desc_e_tx'
        ]
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Below is my controller:

```
$searchModel = new ReportSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchStockMovementSummary($stockmovement_summary_from_sales_date, $stockmovement_summary_to_sales_date);
            return $this->render('stockmovementreportsummary', [
                        'search' => 'true',
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'from_dt' => $stockmovement_summary_from_sales_date,
                        'to_dt' => $stockmovement_summary_to_sales_date,
                        'model' => $searchModel,
            ]);
```

Below is my index.php

```
$reports = $dataProvider->getModels();
    $i=1;

    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
    echo "<tr><th>#</th><th>Item</th><th>Total Summary Usage Qty</th><th>Current Stock On Hand</th><th>Measurement</th></tr>";
    foreach ($reports as $report) {
        $item_key = $report['report_item_key'];
        $item_model = Item::find()->where(['item_key' =>$item_key])->one();
        $item_e_desc_tx = $item_model->desc_e_tx;
        $item_c_desc_tx = $item_model->desc_c_tx;
        $item_qty_no = $item_model->qty_no;
        $item_measurement_tx = $item_model->measurement;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $i++ . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . Html::a($item_key, array('stockmovementreportdetailbyitem', 'item_key' => $item_key, 'search' => 'true', 'from_dt' => $from_dt, 'to_dt'=>$to_dt)) . "<br>" . $item_e_desc_tx . "<br>" . $item_c_desc_tx ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $report['total_summary_usage_qty'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $item_qty_no . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $item_measurement_tx . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
        'pagination'=>$dataProvider->pagination,     
    ]);
```

Comment: It would help us to help you if you could show some code. What is your model, view and controller? Are you using a default dataProvider?

Comment: Are you using `GridView` to display models?

Comment: hi! im not using gridview. im using for loop.

Comment: If you need table, why not use `GridView` for that purpose? Plus it already has pagination.

Comment: yes i tried using gridview the first time but its not working

Comment: Maybe you should try and fix the gridView, rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView should be used but I do not think it will help. Do you by any chance use POST instead of GET to filter the results? If you take a look here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Pagination.php#L257 at the createUrl function you will see that it uses getQueryParams http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#getQueryParams() to create the query string. If you use POST then this function will not pick up the params properly hence the next page pagination will fail.

Ok, because you actually do use POST then you have to create your own pagination function that takes post into consideration. Or just use GET. You are not performing any operations to the DB you can safely use GET. It is better for everybody.

Comment: yes in my search button, i use activeform wih method post. $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'method' => 'post',
            'action' => ['report/stockmovementreportsummary', 'search' => 'true', 'from_dt'=> $from_dt, 'to_dt'=>$to_dt],
        ]);

Comment: see my last paragraph from the response, in short use GET not POST.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the code in your action.
Read [this documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html).

And edit `$dataProvider->pagination`